# can PyAudio handle non-interleaved buffers?

Tags: python, numpy, pyaudio

I'm having trouble passing non-interleaved stereo data to PyAudio.

#### update (rewording question substantially)

The examples given in the PyAudio docs show how to pass *interleaved* data with a callback.  A buffer of interleaved stereo data has a shape of `(nframes, 2)`, and looks like this:

```
array([[f0l, f0r],
       [f1l, f1r],
       [f2l, f2r],
       ...], dtype=float32)
```

Partly for didactic reasons, I'd like to use *non-interleaved* data in my callback.  Reading the docs, I think a buffer of non-interleaved stereo data has a shape of `(2, nframes)` and looks like this:

```
array([[f0l, f1l, f2l, ...],
       [f0r, f1r, f2r, ...]], dtype=float32)
```

And AFAICT, the call to set up the stream in non-interleaved mode should `OR` in the non-interleaved bit in the format argument like this:

```
PA_NONINTERLEAVED = 0x80000000
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32 | PA_NONINTERLEAVED,
                channels=DEFAULT_CHANNEL_COUNT,
                rate=SRATE,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)
```

But when I try to run this, it segfaults or blasts my ears with digital noise or doesn't play anything -- all hallmarks of a memory smasher somewhere.

Has anyone succeeded in passing non-interleaved data to PyAudio?

#### original question (and full code example)

The following code is supposed to write a 440Hz sinewave to the left channel and a 442Hz sinewave to the right channel.

Instead it segfaults.

I have successfully run a similar test using interleaved numpy data, but was hoping I could keep the channel data separate.  Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

```
# python sketches/s05.py 
"""
PyAudio / NumPy example: synthesize and play stereo sine waves
using non-interleaved buffers
"""

import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import time

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

SRATE = 44100
DEFAULT_CHANNEL_COUNT = 2
DEFAULT_FRAME_COUNT = 1024
# from http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html
PA_NONINTERLEAVED = 0x80000000

class Sinner:
    def __init__(self, freq, channel):
        self._dtheta = freq * 2.0 * np.pi / SRATE
        self._theta = 0.0
        self._channel = channel

    def render(self, buffer, frame_count):
        thetas = np.arange(frame_count) * self._dtheta + self._theta
        np.sin(thetas, buffer[self._channel])
        self._theta += frame_count * self._dtheta

sin_l = Sinner(440.0, 0)
sin_r = Sinner(442.0, 1)
out_data = np.zeros((DEFAULT_CHANNEL_COUNT, DEFAULT_FRAME_COUNT),
                    dtype=np.float32)

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global sin_l, sin_r, out_data

    if (out_data.shape[1] != frame_count):
        # resize numpy array if needed
        out_data = np.zeros((DEFAULT_CHANNEL_COUNT, frame_count),
                            dtype=np.float32)
    sin_l.render(out_data, frame_count)
    sin_r.render(out_data, frame_count)

    print(out_data[0])
    print(out_data[1])
    return (out_data * 0.4, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32 | PA_NONINTERLEAVED,
                channels=DEFAULT_CHANNEL_COUNT,
                rate=SRATE,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()
while stream.is_active(): time.sleep(0.1)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: 'The examples given in the PyAudio docs show how to pass interleaved data with a callback'. Could you please link the example? I would find itreally useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt the didactic superiority of non-interleaved data, it would be interesting to hear the other part of your reasons.

Are you aware that matplotlib plots the columns if you pass it a 2-dimensional array?

Also, it looks like you're overlooking the `order` setting of your array. What you're saying in your question only makes sense if you are assuming `order='C'`. You should be able to get the behavior you want by running your array through [numpy.asfortranarray()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asfortranarray.html) and then passing the buffer to PyAudio (but *without* using the `PA_NONINTERLEAVED` flag!).
Note that this will make an unnecessary copy of your data in many cases.

Given your example code, you seem to misunderstand how PortAudio's "non-interleaved" mode works. In this mode, PortAudio assumes that input and output data are C-arrays of pointers to a bunch of other arrays each holding the data for one channel. To be able to use this, you would need to get pointers to each row of your NumPy arrays. I don't know if that's possible in pure Python ...

Finally, some advertisement: You should consider using the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module instead of PyAudio. It still uses interleaved data and the channels are stored in columns, but it directly supports NumPy arrays and should be much easier to install and use than PyAudio.

Comment: FWIW, I already have working code using interleaved data and I plan to stick with it.  Thus the whole non-interleaved exercise really is, as I say, didactic.  But doesn't `a = np.zeros((2, 5), dtype=float32)` in fact produce two arrays, five elements long, such that a[0] would be the left channel in non-interleaved mode?  (And though I've had no problems installing and using PyAudio, sounddevice appears to solve http://stackoverflow.com/q/36970623/558639, so I'll take a deeper look.)

Comment: Yes, `a[0]` would be a NumPy array holding the left channel, but when you pass the buffer belonging to `a` to PortAudio, it expects there to be pointers but it will only find audio data (and very likely create the errors you described). Support for `PA_NONINTERLEAVED` would have to be explicitly handled by PyAudio and I guess it isn't. I was thinking about implementing this in the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module, but up to now, nobody seemed to be needing this ...

Answer (score 0):

No, at least still in version 0.2.11. When recording something this callback code allows to project only on one channel, in the example the first channel. The trick is to use NumPy and arrange the data into a array (cube) with dimensions frame x channel x data (= `SAMPLE_WIDTH`) and then project onto the first channel (0):

```py
# 16 bits sample width
SAMPLE_WIDTH = 2


def __audio_callback__(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
    channels = int(len(in_data) / (SAMPLE_WIDTH * frame_count))
    buffer = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=uint8)
    first_channel = buffer.reshape(frame_count, channels, SAMPLE_WIDTH)[:, 0, :].tobytes()
    audio_samples.append(first_channel)
    # when not recording, return here the processed data as first tuple part
    return None, pyaudio.paContinue
```