# PyAudio: when is it safe to modify the callback buffer?

Tags: python, numpy, pyaudio

A typical PyAudio callback operating in output mode is:

```
def callback(ignored, frame_count, time_info, status):
    buffer = <fill and return a buffer with frame_count samples of data>
    return (buffer, pyaudio.paContinue)
```

I haven't tried it, but I'm pretty sure that if I started modifying `buffer` immediately after the callback returns that it would corrupt the data as it gets played -- true?

So the question: Is there a way to know when PyAudio has finished playing the buffer?  If so, I'd like to create a buffer pool so I can reuse buffers after PyAudio is finished with them.

(If there isn't a mechanism for finding out when PyAudio has finished with a buffer, the only alternative I see is to allocate a fresh buffer at each callback.  Perhaps that's not a big issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the callback runs in a different thread, it's basically never safe to access your `buffer` from the main thread and you cannot know *immediately* when the callback is finished (at least not without blocking the callback, which you should try to avoid). However, you can cycle through a list of buffers and as long as their total length is longer than the system latency you should be *reasonably* safe ...

What's typically done in this case is to use a lock-free ringbuffer to transport audio data in and out of the callback. Sadly, PortAudio's ringbuffer implementation is not part of their shared library and AFAIK it isn't available in PyAudio either (nor in the `sounddevice` module).

Anyway, Python isn't really the best environment for doing realtime audio in the first place, so you'll have to live with some limitations and you'll never really have both reliable performance *and* very low latencies.

Comment: ...and this is why I've switched to Matthias's great `sounddevice` module. :) Its callback method passes in a buffer to fill, so there's no question about when it's safe to use it.